# browse() method in odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

In OperERP 7,

There is a statement as

```
 context = dict(context or {})

 data = self.read(cr, uid, ids, [], context=context)[0]
```

In Odoo 8, I want to write this statement in new style. I tried the below, but it wont work.

```
 context = dict(self._context or {})

 data = self.browse([], context)[0]
```

Here how do I pass the context value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `with_context` to change current environment's context. i.e.

```
ctx = dict(self._context or {})
rec = self.with_context(ctx).browse()
```