# Method read declaration in odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

In **openerp** ,

```
 data = self.read(cr, uid, ids, [], context=context)[0]
```

What is the equivalent statement of above in **odoo 8**. I am getting wrong result when I used the below statement.

```
data = self.with_context(context).browse(self.ids)[0]
```

I am new to **odoo 8**, Please help me on this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [browse() method in odoo 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602802/browse-method-in-odoo-8)

Comment: Are you trying to read the values which the user introduced in the form?

Comment: @Daniel, it is not duplicate of you mentioned. I am asking the exact statement for the above old openerp declaration.

Comment: @forvas, sorry I am not getting your question

Comment: I mean if you used that read in OpenERP7 code to get the data the user had introduced in a form. Because when I wanted to get the data the user had introduced in a wizard form, I used that line. In that case I can tell you how you can do that in Odoo 8, is much easier.

Comment: why you need to browse record with context. there are other possible option to read the record in odoo v8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite often I am lazy and just use the V7 api. It still works fine.

```
@api.v8
def function_i_want_to_edit_that_uses_v8_api(self):
    # omg where are my cr and uid objects
    # oh... i can just smuggle :-P
    data = self.browse(self._cr, self._uid, self._ids, context=self._context)
```

But this should also work:

```
@api.v8
def function_i_want_to_edit_that_uses_v8_api(self):
    data = self.browse(self._ids)
```

Maybe the only problem is the missing `_`? Also make sure that any functions in which you use this are v8-enabled, eg. decorated with `@api.v8` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of browse and read method in **odoo v7** which method called from button.

```
def call_button(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if not context: context = {}
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        print rec.name
    '''or '''
    for rec in self.read(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        print rec.get('name')
```

if you need to write the same method in **odoo v8** you can write like,

```
@api.one
def call_button(self):
    print self # which will return you a record set using you can directly access fields and method of that model
    print self.read() # which will return you a list of dictionary
```

and if you want to pass context you can use `with_context` with your environment.

hope this helps.